# App Crashes While tried to buy already purchsed item

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have used in App Billing Version 3 while implementing in app purchase in my app, and for that i follow the logic they have given in their sample code. Every thing works fine, But when i tried to buy an already purchased item the app crash.

Is their any way to control the crash, and instead show an toast message to the user that this item is already purchased.

Cheers 
Rahul

Comment: Yes, there is. -- Sorry, couldn't resist... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `RESPONSE_CODE`, which will be `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED` if the user already owns it.

See here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html

Comment: Ok...i will try that..one more question at the time when we tried to buy already purchased item what is the result code..is the result code is equal to RESULT_OK and where i can made this check BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED, is it onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) method.

Comment: @Rahul, did you get an answer on this. I have an unmanaged item, but gives a nullpointer/crash when item already purchased once. Looks like mService=null